# Video input field for Wordpress'es video post format

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-4.0

I am writing a new wordpress theme and I added video post format using wordpress'es docs, but the problem is that I don't see any fields for getting video's URL to display it on my single.php page (I want it to be replaced with featured image).

I looked for it on the internet and found nothing useful, the best thing that I found was the way to get url from the content, which is not what I'm looking for as I want my theme to be able show videos in content separately .

Thank you any help would be appreciated

Comment: Use custom fields then. The video shortcode in embedded in `the_content()`

Comment: I need to make it easy for my theme users, I don't want to ask them to add it using wordpress'es custom fields. Beside, I've seen a lot of themes having this field after selecting video post format, I guess it shouldn't be that hard to add